# Blank rows are being inserted after every time i add values in row in my DATABASE

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have following codes and it runes successfully and says that data successfully entered but when i check the database table, every time i insert data (Despite of that successful operation) i get one blank row.
Inshort no data is being inserted although the code says operation successful

CODE:
**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
$host= "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db = "db";

 $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
 if (!$con) 
 {  echo "Failed to Connect"; }
 else
 {  echo "Connection successful";}
 ?>
```

CODE:**addInfo.php**

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
$username = $_POST["username"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
$flag = false;
$sql = "insert into userInfo values('$username','$email','$mobile');";
$flag=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($flag!==false)
{
    echo "Data inserted successfully!";
}
else
{
echo "Error in insertion" . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

CODE:**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="addinfo.php">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
    <td>Mobile:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mobile"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any type of help you guys can do,please proceed,

Comment: [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) disaster waiting to happen... Please use prepared statements, or at least sanitize your users's input

Comment: Look at `name="name"` in your input, then again at `$username = $_POST["username"];`. And you're not specifying the method, so it defaults to GET. You need `<form method="POST" action="addinfo.php">`

Comment: corrected and used the POST tag as u suggested, still the same error.Blank rows are getting inserted!

Comment: What are the column name of `userInfo` table?

Comment: username,email,mobile are the columns

Comment: @ShikharShah Update your question with the code you're currently running. And, add [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) on top of your `addInfo.php`, directly after `<?php`.

Comment: codes updated:)

Comment: Well, does the error-reporting yield anything? If not, what does `print_r($_POST);` output?

Comment: where to add this line print_r($_POST); ?

Comment: In `addInfo.php`. But like I said before, does any error-messages appear after you added the error-reporting? That could tell us a lot what we're dealing with.

Comment: You edited your question to use the right POST array/name attribute. Please don't "fix" your code since it will be contradictive to the (accepted) answer given. I had to perform a rollback to a previous revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I) Changes***

- Change `$username = $_POST["username"];` to `$username = $_POST["name"];`
- Add `method="POST"` in `<form>`
- Use [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid *security vulnerability*.

***II) Updated Code***

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
$host= "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db = "db";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
if ($con->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}
?>
```

**addInfo.php**

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO userInfo (`username`,`email`,`mobile`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["mobile"]);

if($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "Data inserted successfully!";
} else {
  echo "Error in insertion" . $con->errno;
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Information</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="addinfo.php" method="POST">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
          <td>Email:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
          <td>Mobile:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="mobile"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

***III) Quick Start***

- [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [$mysqli->query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

***IV) Have A Look***

- [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)
- [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)